# How to do revert or rollback of an update in CosmosDB?

Tags: transactions, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm doing an upsert of a JSON document in **Azure CosmosDB SQL API** as part of a transaction. I'm using the **SDK** `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core`.

I also have another **SQL Server** update which takes place in the same **transaction scope** (not .NET transaction scope class). If the **SQL Server** update fails, I want to revert/rollback the change made to the CosmosDB. What command or option I should use from the SDK to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking here is whether your Cosmos DB update can participate in an automatically managed distributed transaction, and I believe the answer is no.  Transaction support in Cosmos is somewhat limited.

- Any transaction supported by the Cosmos DB engine is scoped to a single partition in a single container, meaning, you cannot update documents in different containers, or even different partitions within the same container as part of a single transaction.
- Until recently the only way to get transaction support was by using a server-side stored procedure.  With [version 3.4 of the .Net SDK](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/whats-new-in-azure-cosmos-db-nov-2019/) you can now execute transactions from your .Net code, but the single partition restriction still applies.
- There is no built-in support for participating in distributed transactions with other databases or services.

In order to perform operations in your Cosmos DB and SQL Server databases as part of a single Atomic transaction you will need to write some code to manage that yourself. [Check here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/01/patterns-for-distributed-transactions-within-a-microservices-architecture/) for a good primer on distributed transactions.